# Symfony 5.1 : Unrecognized field: activation_token

Tags: php, database, symfony, orm

I am working on a project with Symfony 5.1 and I have a problem with a line of code that worked fine in another project but with the current project it gives me an error even though my code is correct.

My activation_token column does exist in table but it gives me the error.

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['activation_token' => $token]);
```

In another function I used the code below and it works:

```
$user_exist = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $new_email]);
```

The first code doesn't work and the second code does work while both attributes are in my database.

My user entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"email"}, message="There is already an account with this email")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     */
    private $isVerified = false;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $activationToken;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $activationCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Entreprise::class, mappedBy="user", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $entreprises;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->entreprises = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function isVerified(): bool
    {
        return $this->isVerified;
    }

    public function setIsVerified(bool $isVerified): self
    {
        $this->isVerified = $isVerified;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName(string $firstName): self
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLastName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    public function setLastName(string $lastName): self
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(?\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    public function setUpdatedAt(?\DateTimeInterface $updatedAt): self
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getActivationToken(): ?string
    {
        return $this->activationToken;
    }

    public function setActivationToken(?string $activationToken): self
    {
        $this->activationToken = $activationToken;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getActivationCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->activationCode;
    }

    public function setActivationCode(?string $activationCode): self
    {
        $this->activationCode = $activationCode;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Entreprise[]
     */
    public function getEntreprises(): Collection
    {
        return $this->entreprises;
    }

    public function addEntreprise(Entreprise $entreprise): self
    {
        if (!$this->entreprises->contains($entreprise)) {
            $this->entreprises[] = $entreprise;
            $entreprise->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeEntreprise(Entreprise $entreprise): self
    {
        if ($this->entreprises->removeElement($entreprise)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($entreprise->getUser() === $this) {
                $entreprise->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

My database capture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LAVN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the property name rather than the DB column name, so :

```
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['activationToken' => $token]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works great but so far i didn't understand why activation_token was working in another project but with this project no.

Comment: You are right in my other project I did have the activation_token property in my User entity. I just checked.